# In OAuth2 with PKCE, why must the challenge be encrypted in responses?

Tags: oauth-2.0, digital-signature, pkce

In https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636#section-4.4 it is stated that the challenge can be associated with the authorization code by including it in the code, but only in encrypted form (alternatively store it on the server, which is not related to my question). Why must it be encrypted?

It seems obvious to me that the challenge should not be possible to alter, because then a later request for an access code could include a new challenge that was never presented to the server, and for which an attacker conveniently has a code verifier ready. However, to protect against modification, it would be sufficient to include a signature in the authorization code -- encrypting the challenge would not be necessary.

Section 4.4 also says that "The server MUST NOT include the "code_challenge" value in client requests in a form that other entities can extract". Suppose that either the requestor or a third party could extract the code challenge -- why is that harmful? The requestor already knows the code challenge, and a third-party attacker cannot derive the code verifier from it.

Answer (score 0):

> Why must it be encrypted?

With PKCE implementation the authorization server does not have the client secret. It uses the `code_challenge` (an encrypted form of `code_verifier`). you can treat `code_verifier` as `client_secret`. Since `client_secret` cannot be sent through the front channel we are encrypting it. Once the `authorization_code` is generated see [section 4.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636#section-4.6) how the authorization server verifies it. Here `authorization_code` and `code_challenge` are sent through the back channel.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really understand this argument -- this doesn't seem to explain at all why the code challenge needs to be encrypted. Maybe it would help to describe an attack scenario that becomes possible when assuming that the authorization code contains an unencrypted copy of the code challenge (that is secured against modification with a signature so an attacker cannot forge the authorization code -- think of a ficticious scenario where the authorization code is a JWT that contains the code challenge in its payload).

Answer (score 0):

The instructions in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636#section-4.4 apply to a generic `code_challenge_method`.

If the "plain" method is used, where `code_challenge` equals `code_verifier`, and the server does not protect (encrypt) the `code_challenge`, an attacker can obtain both the `code_verifier` and the `authorization_code` to forge a malicious access token request.